# How to avoid typecasting or object class checking in state design pattern?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, state-pattern

I am implementing a state manager to control an object state pattern. My `StateManager` has a property `currentMode`, which can be of type `PenState`, `EraserState`, `ZoomState` (all subclasses of `State`).

But, in the receiver side while fetching `currentMode`, how can I avoid typecasting? what is wrong with the design? what is correct way to do it?

```
State *state = [StateManager sharedManager].currentMode;
if([state isKindOfClass:[PenState Class]]) //how to avoid this type checking
{
    penState *penState = (PenState*)state;
    CGSize penSize = penState.size;
}
```

My classes

```
@interface PenState : State

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *color;
@property(nonatomic,assign) CGSize size;

@end

@interface StateManager : NSObject
{

}
@property(nonatomic,strong)State *currentMode;

@end
```

**Updated:**

Do I need to maintain enum's in State Class

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Mode)
    {
        None = 0,
        Pen,
        Eraser,
        Zoom
    };

@protocol StateProtocol <NSObject>
-(Mode)toolbarMode;
@end

@implementation WriteState

-(Mode)toolbarMode
{
    return Pen;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the state pattern is that the states should be interchangeable from the point of view of the state machine, so each state should conform to a protocol (or perhaps in your case a superclass should present the common interface) which provides all of the common requirements. As such, all of your states (your tools) should accept a size and an action which uses the specified size, either setting the size of a pen and drawing a line, or setting the zoom size and executing the zoom.

Where there are differences in the state you could do a class check, and this should be relatively uncommon and in relatively specific code. If the code is specific then you should usually know the class that is expected so you can just typecast.

Inheritance and protocols can be used to create subsets of your states too, so you can have tool states (with size), but also drawing states (with colour) for example, and then you can continue to typecast to the super class / protocol and not be concerned with each specific implementation class.

Comment: As per the answer @Wain, Do I need to maintain enum's(or similar concept) in the base State class? (Please see the updated question) is that you are mentioning?

Comment: Not unless you have a specific need for them. Generally the implementation class for each state should just conform to protocols and implement the methods in specific ways for the purpose of that state.

Comment: Also, unless you want to make it easy to change your state code in the future (add new states), I'm not sure the state pattern and its complexity will help your design. You only have three states. Could their logic fit nicely in a case statement? Simple is also a pattern. On the other hand, if it's 50 lines of code for each case, separate classes might be better. Just because your application has "state" does not mean you will benefit from the State pattern.

Comment: My application has many states >15, here just for example i have posted 3 states... as @Wain Now i have implemented a protocol in State(similar protocols has to be implemented for other methods) and in my WriteState class i defined the protocol.